# How can I change home folder of ARC Welder?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

When I start ARC Welder for the first time, ARC Welder ask me to set a writable home folder for storing apps. Now I want to change the location of this folder, however I can't find any option to change. So how can I change the location of this folder?

PS: I use Ubuntu and I don't want to reinstall it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like we need to add an option to do that.

For now here is what you can do without having to re-download it:

1. Launch ArcWelder
2. Type `chrome://inspect/#apps` into your browser's URL bar.
3. Click the link to inspect ArcWelder
4. Type `chrome.storage.local.clear()` into the javascript console.
5. Restart ArcWelder. It should again ask you to choose a directory.